# Final image form fancy product design fpd_data?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using fancy product design plug-in for woo commerce in my wordpress site.
After an succesfull order, fancy product data is saved in order_items_meta table with fpd_data key.
I manage to fetch data through order number and want to show final images(canvas) in my print for delivery note(print invoice/reciept) from fpd_data.

Original fetched data is in this format:

```
"{\"product\":[{\"title\":\"Marshmallow View\",\"thumbnail\":\"https:..........
```

After stripslashes(), i am getting :

```
{"product":[{"title":"Marshmallow View","thumbnail":"htt...........so on
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been having the very same problem. After some playing around, I might have found a direction:

1. json_decode it `$data = json_decode($data_raw);'
2. Then you target what you want by working through the objects and arrays like so (for me this was the actual path) '$source = $fpd_data->product[0]->elements[1]->source;'

When it's an object you use "->" to move down, and if it's an instance of an array you use brackets "[]".  Hope that helps!